# Swift Vapor server: how to return nested dictionaries in get request?

Tags: ios, vapor

I am getting started with Vapor in Xcode to build a simple server to support my app. I am trying to understand how to properly build JSON objects I can return for example in a get request.

I have the following:

```
drop.get { request in
    let date:TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    let dictionary:[String:String] = ["name":"e2","age":"3"]
    return try JSON(node: [
        "time":date,
        "t1" : "abc",
        "t2" : dictionary
        ])
}
```

This does not work, it tells me that "argument labels (node:) do not match any available overloads"

How can I build JSON that includes strings, numbers and nested dictionary like above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every value in the `Node` object initialiser must be a `Node` as well. You just need to call `makeNode()` on anything that isn't already a Node.

```
return try JSON(node: [
    "time": date.makeNode(),
    "t1" : "abc",
    "t2" : dictionary.makeNode()
])
```